# VSTFS build failed at Publish step

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-build-task, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using the VSTFS CI/CD pipeline to automate my .NET Core 5.0 with Angular 12 web application.

It failing the build at Publish step (see below screenshot) with error:

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2021-12-13T20:19:46.9855025Z   operable program or batch file.
2021-12-13T20:19:46.9917349Z D:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\58\s\src\WebUI\WebUI.csproj(85,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 9009.
2021-12-13T20:19:47.0482106Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2021-12-13T20:19:47.0496257Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects :
```

[image]

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `npm` is not found by the agent. Make sure Node is installed globally on the machine and npm has been added to the system wide path environment variable.

Or add the Node Tool Installer task to your workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by deleting the npm publish tag in WebUI project file.